# How to map symlink target path in a shared nfs directory between host and guest machines?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, symlink, nfs

I am running a VM using chef provisioner. I have a shared nfs directory defined in the following manner:

`"synced_folders": [
      {
        "host_path": "~/data",
        "guest_path": "/var/www",
        "type": "nfs"
....`

I created a symlink in a chef recipe using chef `link` function. It works fine on the VM. However since the same path does not exist on the host the link is broken. So is there a way to map the symlink from guest to the host?
For example, on the VM I create a link between `/var/www/file1` to `/var/www/file2`. This path will be broken on the host machine. it would be great if I can map the path on the host machine to be `~/data/file2`

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, NFS does not offer this feature. Samba does, no idea of VBox's shared disk helpers do.